# DAX count occurrence based on multiple criteria

Tags: count, powerbi, calculated-columns, dax, find-occurrences

this might be simple but I need your help!

I need to add a column to my raw data that contains the total count of unique sub events for every unique ID when the sub event type = Type A, and the result should be displayed in the first Type A found on the list and show zeros on the remaining lines for such ID.

Hopefully the mock-up table example can illustrate how my raw data is structured and what I need as an outcome (COLUMN J)

[image: Table Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following calculated column should do the trick:

```
Type A Events by ID = 
VAR FirstRow = 
CALCULATE(
    MIN('Log'[Index]),
    FILTER('Log', 'Log'[ID] = EARLIER('Log'[ID]) && 'Log'[Sub Event Type] = "Type A")
)
RETURN
IF(
    'Log'[Index] = FirstRow,
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT('Log'[Sub Event]),
        FILTER('Log', 'Log'[ID] = EARLIER('Log'[ID]) && 'Log'[Sub Event Type] = "Type A")
    ),
    0
)
```

Not sure how you determine the first Type A row found so I added an index column and retrieved the qualified row with the minimum index. (That's what `FirstRow` is doing)

Then it'll return the distinct count of `Sub Event` with the same `ID` and `Sub Event Type` is Type A if it's the first row, otherwise return 0.

Feel free to clarify or modify it to suit your case.

Result:

[image: result]

Comment: Hi @Marcelo Aguilar Does this solve your issue after all?

Comment: Hi, the proposed solution works on smalls data sets I used for testing, unfortunately, when scaling this up, it's too slow... so far I'm using it on some partitions of my data to get the work done.Thanks!